# How resolve "logic" is an unknown type error in Vivado synthesis?

Tags: verilog, synthesis, vivado

the verilog code at

output  logic           PIPE_PCLK;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logic` and `bit` are added in SystemVerilog 2012.

You need to tell Vivado the file is in SystemVerilog.  It's documented
in chapter 8 of UG901 - Vivado Design Suite User Guide: Synthesis and
Appendix B of UG900 - Vivado Design Suite User Guide: Logic Simulation.

> Targeting SystemVerilog for a Specific File
>
> By default, the Vivado synthesis tool compiles *.v files with the
>     Verilog 2005 syntax and *.sv files with the SystemVerilog syntax.  To
>     target SystemVerilog for a specific *.v file in the Vivado IDE,
>     right-click the file, and select Source Node Properties. In the Source
>     File Properties window, change the File Type to SystemVerilog, and
>     click OK.
>
> Tcl Command to Set Properties
>
> Alternatively, you can use the following Tcl command in the Tcl
>     Console:
>
> ```
> set_property file_type SystemVerilog [get_files <filename>.v]
> ```

Depending on your taste, you may want the suffix to be `.sv` since it's
SystemVerilog.  If you are creating the file from Vivado, you should
select SystemVerilog instead of Verilog.

You may also want to make sure the file's `library` property is not
empty.  It usually defaults to `xil_defaultlib` which works.  But on
some occasions (I don't know the exact conditions for this to happen),
it defaults to empty, and you get a strange error like "Incorrect
project file syntax" when you try to simulate it.  It's next to the
"Type" property in the GUI.

Comment: Good catch, I haven't used SystemVerilog yet -- I'll leave my answer up as a signpost, but I think yours is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

“logic” is an unknown type **in Verilog (which is distinct from SystemVerilog)** -- means that the word "logic" is not the name of a valid type. Usually an `output` port needs to be of type `reg`, and an `input` port would be of type `wire`.

See Verilog Reference Guide https://sutherland-hdl.com/pdfs/verilog_2001_ref_guide.pdf page 13:

```
variable_type is one of the following:  

reg      a variable of any bit size; unsigned unless explicitly declared as signed  
integer  a signed 32-bit variable  
time     an unsigned 64-bit variable  
real     a double-precision floating point variable  
realtime same as real
```

Page 3 has the list of reserved keywords; note that `logic` is not a verilog keyword so unless it's something that you defined, that word has no meaning.

Comment: Actually Vivado supports SystemVerilog which has `logic` and `bit`.  See my answer.